# Не ждать ответа smtp

Tags: php

Есть скрипт регистрации юзеров, и при успешной реге нужно слать письмо. Использую smtp Яндекса, но сама отправка и подключение к смтп серверу занимает время, как асинхроно отправить, не ждать ответа?...

Сейчас перекидываю на страницу с гет параметрами, и аяксом шлю, но это костыль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Правильный. Используйте очередь(ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ, Gearman ...)
2. Тоже неплохой, но есть свои заморочки. На базе https://github.com/reactphp/http напишите внутренний сервер который будет принимать сообщения и отсылать емайлы. Т.е. отдали ему команду, и не ждите ответа.
3. Больше как хак. Linux  позваляет запускать процессы на бэкграунде. Можно запустить скрипт отправки через http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php добавив `1 > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &` в конце команды.

   > `exec('php mailer.php  1 > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &');`